# How do I unlock the Random achievement?

Tags: achievements, and-yet-it-moves

In *And Yet It Moves*, there is an achievement called "Random".  It's description simply says to "be lucky".

Somehow, I got it.  How?

Comment: I think it's just Random. *Literally*, as in, "play, and every Y time there's an X % chance to unlock it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is literally random - a lot of people have reported unlocking the achievement in different situations. Some of them situations involving doing nothing at all!

I found a couple of threads about this on the Steam forums too, **[here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-1998293.html)** and **[here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-1728499.html)** if you're interested. :)

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit more conclusive than people speculating in a forum thread...

Comment: Sorry I know, but after doing some research I found the answer to be that there is no "conclusive" answer as to how you unlock this achievement.